# How to output math random array into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-video

I'm just trying to work on my javascript skills and I am trying to make a page that will load up an HTML5 video at random from an array.

Once the video is loaded I am trying to set it so once the video is clicked it will trigger the function to randomize a new video from the array and output the result into the HTML video code.

So every time the user clicks a video will be randomized and begin playing on the page.

I believe I am pretty close with the code I have written so far, but I can't seem to get it to  randomize after it clicked on every click.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="click">
            <section> 
                <div>
                    <video loop autoplay>
                      <source src="videos/1.mpg" type="video/ogg">
                      <source src="videos/1.webm" type="video/mp4">
                      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
                    </video>
                </div>  
        </section>
</a>
```

JavaScript

```
// Loads in Notifier 
$(document).ready(function(){
    swal({   title: "Tap or Swipe to randomize",   
              confirmButtonColor: "#FF1D23",
              confirmButtonText: "Cool!", 
              imageUrl: "images/thumbs-up.jpg",
              timer: 4000
            });
});

//Array of Videos 
var videos = [
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'videos/1.mp4'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'videos/1.webm'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'videos/2.mp4'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'videos/2.webm'}],  
];

//onClick + Action 
$(function() {
    $('a.click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var randomIndex = parseInt(Math.random()*videos.length);
        $(this).find('videos').append('<source src="'+videos[randomIndex]+'" />');      
    });
});


function getRandomVideo() { 
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*video.length);
document.write('<source src="'+videos[number]+'" />');
}

$(function() {
    $('a.click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("hello world");
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
        $(this).html('<source src="'+videos[number]+'" />');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maL12a9L/)

```
//onClick + Action
$('a.click').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var randomIndex = parseInt(Math.random()*videos.length);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('video').html('<source src="'+videos[randomIndex][0].src+'" type="video/ogg" /><source src="'+videos[randomIndex][1].src+'"  type="video/mp4" />');
});
```

I left your data structure alone, although it could be structured better.

Couple of issues. First, you aren't creating your HTML string correctly. You have to use `videos[randomIndex][0].src` (notice the src). Secondly, you are `.append()` when you should be `.html()`. And lastly, you `.find('videos')` instead of `.find('video')`. The tag is a video (no S).

**EDIT:**
Also, you can't do `$(this).find(...)` in that context. `this` refers to the click event, not the `a` tag. You need to get the TARGET of the event `$(e.currentTarget).find('video')`, not the event.

Comment: Wow I guess I have a long way to go on learning haha. 
I'm trying to figure out the code you've provided.

Comment: I've added in the code you've written and when I load the page the video loads in and on click the video disappears and nothing else is placed in. I've checked for any errors in the console and don't receive any either. Also, how would I make it so that the page will randomize onload as well?

Answer (score 1):

`videos[number][0].src` for .mp4 format
and
`videos[number][1].src` for .webm format

and make sure to correct object declaration:

> {type:'mp4', 'src':'videos/2.mp4'}

should be `{type:'mp4', src:'videos/2.mp4'}`